# Can I pre-specify all but one of the arguments in python function to return a callable in python

Tags: python, function, callable

Let's say I define a function in python

```
def f(x,y):
   return(x+y)
```

Now I want to define a function g( __ )=f( __ ,y), i.e. a function for which I already specified a value y and want it to be a callable which takes only one argument. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple lambda function like

```py
g = lambda x: f(x, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

`functools.partial` is what you need:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html

```py
from functools import partial
g = partial(f, y=your_constant_value_for_y)
```

Calling `g(x)` is equivalent to calling `f(x, your_constant_value_for_y)`.

Comment: So Simon Hawe gave the 'lambda function' solution, which seems equivalent in some way. Is there a difference?

Comment: For your use case, probably not. `partial` likely does something similar under the hood. The only case I could make for it, is that it might be a little more readable and clear what your intentions are, but that's up for debate.

Answer (score 0):

In case, you have to pass many arguments:

```
def f(x, *args):
    return (x, args)


def g(x):
    return f(x, 10, 20, 20)
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, of course that would work, but I would have to dynamically define g whenever I need new arguments. I want to be able to do that temporarily. The lambda function solution given by Simon Hawe is exactly what I had in mind.